# Bell's spaceship paradox and equivalence principle

Tags: general-relativity, equivalence-principle

Does Bell's paradox explain why space expands inside a uniformly accelerated rocket - which is locally the same as as a uniform gravitational field as per equivalence principle? Is this why gravity expands space?

Comment: what exactly is meant by a "uniformly accelerated rocket"?

Comment: Having the same proper acceleration in all parts. Not like Rindler acceleration.

Comment: What makes  you think that uniform acceleration expands space?

Comment: Unless you understand what metric equations mean, what Schwartzchild metric means and how it all starts from EP,  let's not waste time.

Comment: what does same proper acceleration in all parts mean? If two spatially distant parts have the same simultaneous acceleration profile, one needs a coordinate system in which that simultaneity occurs. If they share a coordinate system, then you have to worry about pseudo-gravitational time dilation between front and back.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how gravitation time dilation originates. My question was about how gravitational space expansion originates.